# Moving the last element in a list to a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to move the last element in a list to a different one.

I have tried
 `test_list = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] test_list2 = []`
 `test_list2.insert(0, test_list.pop(test_list[-1]))`
but it seems to give an error.

Comment: Please Edit and include the error message in the post

Comment: `list.pop` takes an index not an element.

Answer (score 1):

The list pop method takes an index, not an object. You can pass -1 to it to get the last item from the list, or pass nothing at all since that's the default.

```
test_list2.insert(0, test_list.pop())
```